# Thunderbird not showing mail properly ( php mail() )

Tags: php, email, attachment, thunderbird

I have a little issue with Thunderbird. I'm trying to send a mail from php with an html version and a plain text version and an attachment. The mail is displayed properly in Yahoo, Gmail and Roundcube, but not in Thunderbird. I hope anyone can see what the problem is. Here is the script that generates my mail. $html = html content and $plain = plain text content

```
function preparehtmlmail($html, $plain) {

preg_match_all('~<img.*?src=.([\/.a-z0-9:_-]+).*?>~si',$html,$matches);
$i = 0;
$paths = array();

foreach ($matches[1] as $img) {
$img_old = $img;

if(strpos($img, "http://") == false) {
  $uri = parse_url($img);
  $paths[$i]['path'] = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$uri['path'];
  $content_id = md5($img);
  $html = str_replace($img_old,'cid:'.$content_id,$html);
  $paths[$i++]['cid'] = $content_id;
}
}

$boundary = "--".md5(uniqid(time()));
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"$boundary\"\n";
$headers .= "From: orders@harliespeed.com\r\n";
$multipart = '';
$multipart .= "--$boundary\n";
$kod = 'utf-8';
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=$kod\n";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n";
$multipart .= "$plain\n\n";
$multipart .= "--$boundary\n";
$kod = 'utf-8';
$multipart .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=$kod\n";
$multipart .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: Quot-Printed\n\n";
$multipart .= "$html\n\n";

foreach ($paths as $path) {
if(file_exists($path['path']))
  $fp = fopen($path['path'],"r");
  if (!$fp)  {
    return false;
  }

$imagetype = substr(strrchr($path['path'], '.' ),1);
$file = fread($fp, filesize($path['path']));
fclose($fp);

$message_part = "";

switch ($imagetype) {
  case 'png':
  case 'PNG':
        $message_part .= "Content-Type: image/png";
        break;
  case 'jpg':
  case 'jpeg':
  case 'JPG':
  case 'JPEG':
        $message_part .= "Content-Type: image/jpeg";
        break;
  case 'gif':
  case 'GIF':
        $message_part .= "Content-Type: image/gif";
        break;
}

$message_part .= "; file_name = \"$path\"\n";
$message_part .= 'Content-ID: <'.$path['cid'].">\n";
$message_part .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
$message_part .= "Content-Disposition: inline; filename = \"mail_logo.jpg\"\n\n";
$message_part .= chunk_split(base64_encode($file))."\n";
$multipart .= "--$boundary\n".$message_part."\n";

  }

  $multipart .= "--$boundary--\n";
  return array('multipart' => $multipart, 'headers' => $headers);
```

}

Comment: I get only the image displayed, but no text. I'll post the php code.

Comment: You really should use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) to generate mime messages. They're far far easier to use, and could reduce that entire script down to about 10 lines of code (not including the content of the email itself).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use multipart MIME parts to compose correctly your message. One multipart for your text/html versions, and another multipart for the HTML and the image.

For HTML and text versions, you should use multpart/alternative, and for the HTML and the image, you should use multipart/related. Your email should like like this (I indent for readability):

```
Content-Type:multipart/alternative; boundary ---01
  Content-Type:text/plain; boundary ---02
     Your text version content
  ---02
  Content-Type:multipart/related; boundary ---03
     Content-Type:text/html; boundary ---04
       Your HTML version content
     ---04
     Content-Type: image/jpeg; boundary ---05
        Your image content
     ---05
  --- 03
---01
```

You can use [PEAR::Mail](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/) to build your messages

Comment: Nice answer :) there other libraries such as PHPMailer and Swift Mailer to name a couple